# Method to return a List<T> from a List<OwnStruct>, where List<T> then contains only one Property of all OwnStructs in List (C#)

Tags: c#, class, generic-list

I'm struggling with this a little.
I have a `List<HeadStruc_Table>` within my program.

The Class HeadStruct looks like following:

```
public partial class HeadStruct_Table : IComparable<HeadStruct_Table>
    {
        public string colName { get; set; }
        public string colName_edit { get; set; }
        public string alternativeNames { get; set; }
        public int Table_ID { get; set; }
        public bool colFound { get; set; }
        public CheckBox cBox { get; set; }
```

I don't know how to create a method with **parameters** `(List<HeadStruct_Table>, HeadStruct_Table.colName)` that then `return`s a `List<TypeOf(HeadStruct_Table.colName)>` containing only the values of `colName` in this specific case.
Of course it should work for the `bool` and even `CheckBox` property as well.

As parameter `HeadStruct_Table.colName` doesn't work right now, as it is declared as just ***public*** and not ***public static***, do i have to declare it as ***public static*** or is there any other chance to pass the specific property. Maybe by using a predicate?

That's the way it maybe could look like later?

```
public static IList<T> getList<T>(List<HeadStruct_Table> list, Func<HeadStruct_Table, T> getType)
    {
        var newList = new List<T>();
```

I just don't know how to get the special property and then, in the method, just read out those values. I wouldn't like to work with a string as parameter if it works without.

Anyone who has an idea?

That is my first question. I'm open for any advice to improve asking a question in here. Thank You.

Comment: Why don't you use `Select()` ? The method you described is `Select`. It actually accepts `Func<Whatever,T>`. You can already write `list.Select(t=>t.colName).ToList()`

Comment: That was quick and what I needed. Thanks a lot, I really haven't found that method.

Comment: @Envyy System.Linq <-- here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ's [Enumerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) method already does what you want:

```
var newList = list.Select(x => x.colName).ToList();
```